# How to send variables to master layout in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How to send variables to master layout in Laravel 4 ?

Here $categories is not available in master layout :

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $data = array('categories' => $categories);
    $this->layout->content = View::make('catalog.categories', $data);
}
```

My master view :

```
@yield('content')

@if($categories)
   <h1>TEST</h1>
@endif
```

**"TEST" doesn't appear !**

Comment: Not 100% sure, so adding as a comment: Have you tried `$this->layout->with($data)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use this :

```
$this->layout->with('catalog.categories', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that $categories contains any data?

You can also try this:

```
View::make('catalog.categories')->with('categories', $categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with laravel that much, but I think in 4:

```
View::make('catalog.categories', $data); // this looks correct
```

In your `child` template, you should extend the master layout:

```
@extends('layout/master')

// define what will be send to the master:
@section('cats')
    {{ $categories }}
@stop
```

Then in your master:

```
@yield('cats')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem too. As of Laravel 4.2, here's how I got it working:

To pass data to the layout:

```
$this->layout->content = View::share('data', $data);
```

In your case, here's how:

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $data = array('categories' => $categories);
    $this->layout->content = View::share('data', $data);
    $this->layout->content = View::make('catalog.categories', $data);
}
```